# how can we get class name of the entity object in twig view

Tags: symfony, twig

For a example, if we pass a table object to the twig view, how can we get the class name of that object like 'Table'.

```
class Table{

}

$table = new Table();
```

In Twig:

`{{ table.className }}` ---> this should display 'Table'

Answer (score 39):

If you don't want to make this a method on the entity like so:

```
public function getClassName()
{
    return (new \ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();
}
```

then you could create a Twig function or filter.  Here's a function:

```
class ClassTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'class' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('class', [$this, 'getClass'])
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'class_twig_extension';
    }

    public function getClass($object)
    {
        return (new \ReflectionClass($object))->getShortName();
    }
}
```

Use like so:

```
{{ class(table) }}
```

Comment: your first offer works great and it's simpler than what I thought.

Comment: Pay attention that `getShortName` returns only the name of the class without the namespace. Use the `getName` function to get the class' FQN (i.e. namespace and name).

Comment: I just added a getClass method to my entities that return the short name as is shown here. But to use it in the template, I just call entity.class and I get the short name of the class.

Answer (score 9):

In \Twig_Extension you can add tests

```
public function getTests()
{
    return [
        'instanceof' =>  new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'isInstanceof')
    ];
}

/**
 * @param $var
 * @param $instance
 * @return bool
 */
public function isInstanceof($var, $instance) {
    return  $var instanceof $instance;
}
```

And then use like

```
{% if value is instanceof('DateTime') %}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

A slightly updated version of nurikabe's answer:

```
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class ClassTwigExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_class', 'get_class'),
        ];
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'class_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

Use like so:

```
{{ get_class(table) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the `\Twig\Extension\DebugExtension` extension, you can use the [dump](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/dump.html) function:

```
{{ dump(table) }}
```

and visually inspect object the class in the dump output.