# get object entity in twig

Tags: object, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony-2.6

I have an array of objects

```
$objects = fetch objects from DB using Doctrine
```

In twig I want to make a foreach loop that displays the entity class names of the objects. I want this because the array exists out of different objects.

So i try this, ofcourse this does not work.

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {{ object.entityClassName }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can i display the entity class name of the objects in twig?

I looked up this question : 
[how can we get class name of the entity object in twig view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550368/how-can-we-get-class-name-of-the-entity-object-in-twig-view)

Is there a more simple solution to this problem? Wih

Comment: I all ready refer to this in my question.

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is like one in that link You pasted:

```
public function getClassName()
{
    return (new \ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();
}
```

Add method above into your entity and than use it in twig:

```
{{ object.className }}
```

Comment: Ok, i just wondered if it was possible without adding a new method.